# Why bother setting up lights that look green?

Tags: dc, dc-extended-universe, batman-v-superman-dawn-of-justice

Why bother trying to trick Batman when they were already going to kill him?

[image]

[image]

They could have just killed him all the same by luring him into the truck without all the fang-dangled stuff to deceive Batman.

Comment: Wasn't that merely a dream...

Answer (score 13):

The light was there so that Batman would look in the box, providing a small distraction and allowing the guy with the gun to get the drop on him.

[image]

Answer (score 4):

As [Valorum has stated in his answer](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/a/138935/33090), the green light was there to provide additional distraction to allow Superman's minions to get the drop on Batman. However, it also drew Batman deeper into the truck than he would have gone without the green glow and provided more of a distraction for Batman's helpers.

Providing the green glow resulted in Batman being strongly focused upon the inside of the truck.  This results in Batman's helpers being more focused on what was happening inside the truck than they would be otherwise. If your leader is very focused on something, this has a tendency to draw more of your attention to what your leader is focusing on.

Having a green glow which was so deep into the truck drew Batman farther away from his helpers and further restricted the outside area which he could sense (i.e. the truck walls blocked Batman from more of the outside).  Without the green glow, Batman might have been more cautious about proceeding so far into the truck.  The combined effect was to facilitate Superman's minions getting the drop on Batman's helpers, *in addition to Batman*.

[image: Superman's minions get the drop on Batman and his helpers, not auto repeat]

Separating Batman from his helpers was one of the goals of the trap.  It allowed the helpers to be executed without the need to be careful about killing Batman.

The goal of the trap was **not to kill Batman**, at that time. The goal of Superman's minions was to **capture Batman** so that the minion's god, Superman, could confront Batman.<sup>1</sup>  There were various times in the fight sequence where Superman's minions could have been firing weapons at Batman, but distinctly hold off from doing so, even pointing their weapons away from Batman.<sup>2</sup> This implies that they were under orders to capture, not kill Batman. At the end of the fight, they overwhelm him with numbers, hold him down and knock him unconscious.

In Batman's dream, Superman blamed Batman for taking "her" from Superman. Superman wanted the payback to be personal. Superman having his minions kill Batman would not have provided Superman with as much emotional satisfaction as doing the deed for himself.  From Batman's point of view (his dream) this is a personal fight between Batman and Superman. There is no way that the minions would have been the ones to kill Batman in his own dream.

- Superman says: "She was my World. And, you took her from me."
  [image: Batman vs Superman Dream confrontation]

<sup>1. Minions & god are from Batman's point of view. The entire sequence is Batman's dream. In this dream, many things are strongly shaded towards Batman's point of view.</sup>
<sup>2. Part of this could be where the timing of the moves is a bit off. At least to my eye, there are a few points where Superman's minions take a stance which is waiting for a hit from Batman where they set themselves in the position a fraction of a second prior to when they would have had the moves been natural.</sup>

Answer (score 0):

There's no actual reason, the whole thing was a dream.  Dreams are nuts... in dreams, you are incapable of judgment, so all kinds of completely idiotic things tend to happen and somehow you don't notice there's anything wrong with them at the time.

Comment: There does appear to be some logic to the dream, though, as discussed in the other answers.

Comment: Yes of course, because it's also a movie so we the audience need to be able to follow things.  Imagine actually watching someone's dream... if they're anything like my dreams, the audience would just be looking at each other saying "WTF?!?!" and walking out of the theater.  ;)

Comment: @JonathanvanClute To be fair, many audiences already did that for *Batman v Superman*.

Comment: It's not necessarily a dream.  It seems to be a glimspe into the future enabled by Flash, the person we see immediately after who is trying to warn Bruce about what will happen.  In the comics, this kind of thing has happened, where Flash projects himself out of time when running at super speed and brings with him a "wave" of imagery from the future.